Deduction theorem in coq
Trying to understand and formalize the proof of deduction theorem from the book "Introduction to mathematical logic" by Elliott Mendelson.
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

(* Symbols of L theory *)
Parameter atom : Set.

Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Notation "-, F" := (f_not F) (at level 75, right associativity).
Notation "F ~> G" := (f_imp F G) (at level 95, right associativity).

A well-formed formula (wf) C is said to be a consequence in formal theory S of a set Γ of wfs if and only if there is a sequence B1, ..., Bk of wfs such that C is Bk and, for each i, either Bi is an axiom or Bi is in Γ, or Bi is a direct consequence by some rule of inference of some of the preceding wfs in the sequence. Such a sequence is called a proof
(or deduction) of C from Γ. The members of Γ are called the hypotheses or premises of the proof. We use Γ ⊢ C as an abbreviation for "C is a consequence of Γ".
Inductive proof : list formula -> formula -> Prop :=
  | A1: forall {A B: formula}, proof [] (A ~> (B ~> A))
  | A2: forall {A B C: formula}, proof [] ((A ~> (B ~> C)) ~> ((A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C)))
  | A3: forall {A B: formula}, proof [] ((-, B ~> -, A) ~> ((-, B ~> A) ~> B))
  | MP: forall {A B: formula} {Γ: list formula},
      proof Γ (A ~> B) ->
      proof Γ A ->
      proof Γ B.

Proposition 1.9 (Deduction Theorem)
If Γ is a set of wfs and A and B are wfs, and Γ, A ⊢ B, then Γ ⊢ A ⇒ B. In particular, if A ⊢ B, then ⊢ A ⇒ B.
It is proven by induction on Γ in the book, but I am not sure whether I have written it correctly. And how to prove it.
Theorem Deduction: forall (Γ: list formula) (A B: formula),
  proof (cons A Γ) B -> proof Γ (A ~> B).
Proof.
  intros Γ A B H. induction H.


I'm not sure how to answer your question, but one problem with your setup is that your definition of proof has no constructors that would ever allow a nonempty Γ to be instantiated.

Although #firsr-order-logic is tagged, Your system is not a first-order logic Hilbert calculus. And I want to show O'Connor's Proof, which is a first-order Hilbert calculus. See Deduction.v.

I would recommend weakening axioms A1 A2 and A3 with $\Gamma$. It seems like you are also missing the hypothesis case, where F occurs in $\Gamma$.

@Couchy Should I write it like this: A1: forall {A B: formula}, proof Γ (A ~> (B ~> A))? Which means, that in every list of formulas Γ, the axiom formula is valid?

@KijeongLim I don't understand this constructor:
| AXM : forall A : Formula, Prf (A :: nil) A - it says that for every formula there is a prrof a of A if a is in the list of proven formulas.
Does it allow to construct axioms this way? Did you study folProof.v from CoqGym?

@user4035 The consturctor must be required to derive $\varphi \in \Gamma \implies \Gamma \vdash \varphi$. And, referring CoqGym, I have made a library for 1st-order logic.

@KijeongLim "Your system is not a first-order logic Hilbert calculus." - Ahh, yes, first order logic requires quantifiers. Mine is ordinary propositional calculus. I removed the tag.

I proved it. This is incredible.
Require Import List.
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality.
Import ListNotations.

(* Symbols of L theory *)
Parameter atom : Set.

Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Notation "-, F" := (f_not F) (at level 75, right associativity).
Notation "F ~> G" := (f_imp F G) (at level 95, right associativity).

Inductive axiom : formula -> Prop :=
  | A1: forall A B, axiom (A ~> B ~> A)
  | A2: forall A B C, axiom ( (A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C) )
  | A3: forall A B, axiom ((-, B ~> -, A) ~> ((-, B ~> A) ~> B)).

(*
Формула A называется следствием множества формул Γ в S, если
существует последовательсть формул A1, ..., An, что An есть A, и
для любого i Ai есть:
*)
Reserved Notation "Γ |-- l" (at level 98, right associativity).
Inductive proof_chain (Γ : list formula) : list formula -> Prop :=
  | pc_nil : Γ |-- []
  (* либо аксиома *)
  | pc_axiom : forall (A : formula) l, axiom A -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  (* либо элемент Γ *)
  | pc_in : forall (A : formula) (l : list formula), In A Γ -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  (* либо следствие некоторых предыдущих формул по одному из правил вывода *)
  | pc_MP : forall (A B :formula) (l : list formula), In B l -> In (B ~> A) l -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
where "Γ |-- l" := (proof_chain Γ l).

(* Для сокращения утверждения "A есть следствие Γ" мы будем употреблять запись Γ |- A *)
Reserved Notation "Γ |- A" (at level 98, right associativity).
Inductive proof Γ A : Prop :=
  | proof_intro : forall l, Γ |-- (A :: l) -> Γ |- A
where "Γ |- A" := (proof Γ A).

Lemma proof_chain_initial : forall Γ A l, Γ |-- (A :: l) -> Γ |-- l.
Proof. 
intros.
inversion H.
- exact H3.
- exact H3.
- exact H4.
(*now dependent destruction H.*) Qed.

Lemma A3_proof : forall Γ l1 l2,
  Γ |-- l1 -> Γ |-- l2 -> Γ |-- (l1 ++ l2).
Proof.
 intros. induction l1.
* simpl. exact H0.
* simpl. apply proof_chain_initial in H as H1. specialize (IHl1 H1).
inversion H.
  - apply pc_axiom.
    + exact H4.
    + exact IHl1.
  - apply pc_in.
    + exact H4.
    + exact IHl1.
  - apply pc_MP with B.
    + Search _ (In ?a (?b ++ ?c)).
      apply in_or_app.
      left.
      exact H4.
    + apply in_or_app.
      left.
      exact H5.
    + exact IHl1.
Qed.


Lemma дистрибутивность_импликации : forall Γ A B C,
  Γ |- A ~> B ~> C -> Γ |- A ~> B -> Γ |- A ~> C.
Proof.
  intros. inversion_clear H. inversion_clear H0. set (H2 := A3_proof Γ ((A ~> B ~> C) :: l) ((A ~> B) :: l0) H1 H). 
  simpl in H2. set (Hax := (A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C)). 
  set (H3 := pc_axiom Γ Hax ((A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  assert (Hproof : axiom Hax).
  exact (A2 A B C).
  specialize (H3 Hproof H2). clear Hproof.
 (* | pc_MP : forall A B l, In B l -> In (B ~> A) l -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l *)
  set (H4 := pc_MP Γ ((A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C)) (A ~> B ~> C) (Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  assert (Hproof : In (A ~> B ~> C) (Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  simpl. right. left. reflexivity.
  specialize (H4 Hproof). clear Hproof.
  assert (Hproof : In ((A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> A ~> C)
         (Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  simpl. left. reflexivity.
  specialize (H4 Hproof). clear Hproof.
  specialize (H4 H3).
  (*
  A: A ~> C
  B: A ~> B
  (A ~> B) ~> A ~> C
  *)
  set (H5 := pc_MP Γ (A ~> C) (A ~> B) (((A ~> B) ~> A ~> C) :: Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  assert (Hproof : In (A ~> B) (((A ~> B) ~> A ~> C) :: Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  simpl. right. right. right. apply in_or_app. right. simpl. left. reflexivity.
  specialize (H5 Hproof). clear Hproof.
  assert (Hproof: In ((A ~> B) ~> A ~> C) (((A ~> B ) ~> A ~> C) :: Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  simpl. left. reflexivity.
  specialize (H5 Hproof). clear Hproof.
  specialize (H5 H4).
  (* Reserved Notation "Γ |- A" (at level 98, right associativity).
  Inductive proof Γ A : Prop :=
  | proof_intro : forall l, Γ |-- (A :: l) -> Γ |- A
  where "Γ |- A" := (proof Γ A). *)
  set (Hresult := proof_intro Γ (A ~> C) (((A ~> B) ~> A ~> C) :: Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  apply Hresult.
  exact H5.
Qed.

Lemma A_impl_A : forall Γ A,
  Γ |- A ~> A.
Proof.
  intros.
  (* Добавили 1-ю формулу в вывод*)
  set (F1 := (A ~> ((A ~> A) ~> A)) ~> (A ~> (A ~> A)) ~> (A ~> A)).
  assert (Hax : axiom F1).
  exact (A2 A (A ~> A) A).
  assert (Γ1 : Γ |-- F1 :: []).
  apply pc_axiom.
  exact Hax.
  exact (pc_nil Γ).
  clear Hax.

  set (F2 := A ~> ((A ~> A) ~> A)).
  assert (Hax : axiom F2).
  exact (A1 A (A ~> A)).
  assert (Γ2 : Γ |-- F2 :: [F1]).
  apply pc_axiom.
  exact Hax.
  exact Γ1.
  clear Hax.

  clear Γ1.
  set (F3 := (A ~> (A ~> A)) ~> (A ~> A)).
  assert (Γ3 : Γ |-- F3 :: [F2; F1]).
  apply (pc_MP Γ ((A ~> A ~> A) ~> A ~> A) F2 [F2; F1]).
  simpl. auto. 
  simpl. auto.
  exact Γ2.
  clear Γ2.
  
  set (F4 := A ~> (A ~> A)).
  assert (Hax : axiom F4).
  exact (A1 A A).
  assert (Γ4 : Γ |-- F4 :: [F3; F2; F1]).
  apply pc_axiom.
  exact Hax.
  exact Γ3.
  clear Hax.
  clear Γ3.

  set (F5 := A ~> A).
  assert (Γ5 : Γ |--  F5 :: [F4; F3; F2; F1]).
  apply (pc_MP Γ F5 (A ~> A ~> A) [F4; F3; F2; F1]).
  simpl. auto. 
  simpl. auto. 
  exact Γ4.
  clear Γ4;
  
  apply (proof_intro Γ F5 [F4; F3; F2; F1]).
  exact Γ5.
Qed.

(* Пусть B1, ..., Bn --- вывод из Γ \/ {A}, где Bn = B. *)
Lemma Deduction_lemma : forall Γ l A B, In B l ->
  A :: Γ |-- l -> Γ |- A ~> B.
Proof.
  induction l.
- intros. simpl in H. contradiction.
- intros A B HB_in Hвывод. simpl in HB_in.
  destruct HB_in as [Hab | Hin].
  * rewrite Hab in Hвывод. 
    inversion Hвывод.
    + (* Создадим вывод для доказательства цели*)
      assert (Γ1 : Γ |-- B :: []).
      apply pc_axiom.
      exact H1.
      apply pc_nil.
      set (F1 := B ~> (A ~> B)).
      assert (Hproof : axiom F1).
      exact (A1 B A).

      assert (Γ2 : Γ |-- F1 :: [B]).
      apply pc_axiom.
      exact Hproof.
      exact Γ1.
      clear Hproof.
      clear Γ1.

      set (F2 := A ~> B).
      assert (Γ3 : Γ |--  F2 :: [F1; B]).
      apply pc_MP with B.
      simpl.
      auto.
      simpl.
      auto.
      exact Γ2.
      apply proof_intro with [F1; B].
      exact Γ3.
    + simpl in H1.
      destruct H1.
      ++ rewrite H1.
         exact (A_impl_A Γ B).
      ++ assert (Γ1 : Γ |-- B :: []).
         apply pc_in.
         exact H1.
         apply pc_nil.

         set (F1 := B ~> (A ~> B)).
         assert (Hproof : axiom F1).
         exact (A1 B A).

         assert (Γ2 : Γ |-- F1 :: [B]).
         apply pc_axiom.
         exact Hproof.
         exact Γ1.
         clear Hproof.
         clear Γ1.

         set (F2 := A ~> B).
         assert (Γ3 : Γ |--  F2 :: [F1; B]).
         apply pc_MP with B.
         simpl.
         auto.
         simpl.
         auto.
         exact Γ2.
         apply proof_intro with [F1; B].
         exact Γ3.
     + set (F1 := (A ~> B0 ~> B)).
       assert (Γ1 : Γ |- F1).
       apply (IHl A (B0 ~> B)).
       exact H2.
       exact H3.

       inversion Γ1.
       set (F2 := (A ~> (B0 ~> B)) ~> ((A ~> B0) ~> (A ~> B))).
       assert (Hproof : axiom F2).
       exact (A2 A B0 B).

       assert (Γ2 : Γ |--  F2 :: F1 :: l1).
       apply pc_axiom.
       exact Hproof.
       exact H4.
       clear Hproof.
       clear Γ1.

       set (F3 := (A ~> B0) ~> A ~> B).
       assert (Γ3 : Γ |-- F3 :: F2 :: F1 :: l1).
       apply pc_MP with (A ~> B0 ~> B).
       simpl.
       auto.
       simpl.
       auto.
       exact Γ2.

       clear Γ2.
       assert (Γ1 : Γ |- A ~> B0).
       apply (IHl A B0).
       exact H1.
       exact H3.

       inversion Γ1.
       assert (Γ4 :  Γ |-- (F3 :: F2 :: F1 :: l1) ++ ((A ~> B0) :: l2)).
       apply A3_proof.
       exact Γ3.
       exact H5.

       clear Γ3.
       clear H5.
       simpl in Γ4.

       assert (Γ5 : Γ |-- (A ~> B) :: F3 :: F2 :: F1 :: l1 ++ (A ~> B0) :: l2).
       apply pc_MP with (A ~> B0).
       simpl. right. right. right.
       Search _ (In ?a (?b ++ ?c)).
       apply in_or_app.
       simpl. auto.

       simpl. auto.
       exact Γ4.

       apply proof_intro with (F3 :: F2 :: F1 :: l1 ++ (A ~> B0) :: l2).
       exact Γ5.
  * apply proof_chain_initial in Hвывод.
    specialize (IHl A B).
    specialize (IHl Hin Hвывод).
    exact IHl.
Qed.

Theorem Deduction: forall (Γ: list formula) (A B: formula),
  A :: Γ |- B -> Γ |- A ~> B.
Proof.
intros Γ A B [l F]. eapply Deduction_lemma; eauto. now left.
Qed.


Nicely done. The next step after simply proving the theorems (if you wish to take it to the extra step), is to prove them elegantly and extensibly with automation. If you want to take a look at how I might solve the remaining holes, I've done so here: https://pastebin.com/dbvRkPyR

These are not the simplest problems to be tackling if you're new to Coq. Not to dissuade you from them, but you'll have to appreciate the difficulty, and I think you'll learn a lot if you stick with it.
Anyway: When you're tackling a nontrivial problem, it's often best to adopt an "admit-driven" approach and fill out the skeleton of the proof, simply admitting the little details until the end. That's what I've done here, and I leave it as an exercise to finish.
First of all, I've fixed your inductive types so that they accurately reflect the distinct notions of axioms, proof chains, and consequence. I've followed Mendelson as closely as possible here. You could collapse the rules for axiom into that of proof_chain, but I think this way is more organized.
The key for the proof is to generalize your theorem before proving it. You will not get anywhere unless you strengthen the inductive hypotheses, because if you examine Mendelson's proof closely, he uses induction to entail a result on each step in the proof chain. This is why I generalized the theorem into Deduction_lemma, and in general when you do this, you want to introduce the thing you're inducting on (in this case l) as early in the binders as possible. This allows induction to generate the strongest possible induction hypothesis.
You'll notice I import and use the dependent destruction tactic (doc here). Ordinary destruct is too naive to work for dependent types of even modest complexity. You can get much of the same mileage out of inversion and subst, but dependent destruction is a nice power tool.
Require Import List.
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality.
Import ListNotations.

(* Symbols of L theory *)
Parameter atom : Set.

Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Notation "-, F" := (f_not F) (at level 75, right associativity).
Notation "F ~> G" := (f_imp F G) (at level 95, right associativity).

Inductive axiom : formula -> Prop :=
  | A1: forall A B, axiom (A ~> B ~> A)
  | A2: forall A B C, axiom ( (A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C) )
  | A3: forall A B, axiom ((-, B ~> -, A) ~> ((-, B ~> A) ~> B)).

Reserved Notation "Γ |-- l" (at level 98, right associativity).
Inductive proof_chain (Γ : list formula) : list formula -> Prop :=
  | pc_nil : Γ |-- []
  | pc_axiom : forall A l, axiom A -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  | pc_in : forall A l, In A Γ -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  | pc_MP : forall A B l, In B l -> In (B ~> A) l -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
where "Γ |-- l" := (proof_chain Γ l).

Reserved Notation "Γ |- A" (at level 98, right associativity).
Inductive proof Γ A : Prop :=
  | proof_intro : forall l, Γ |-- (A :: l) -> Γ |- A
where "Γ |- A" := (proof Γ A).

Lemma proof_chain_initial : forall Γ A l, Γ |-- (A :: l) -> Γ |-- l.
Proof. intros. now dependent destruction H. Qed.

Lemma A2_proof : forall Γ A B C,
  Γ |- A ~> B ~> C -> Γ |- A ~> B -> Γ |- A ~> C.
Admitted.

Lemma Deduction_lemma : forall Γ l A B, In B l ->
  A :: Γ |-- l -> Γ |- A ~> B.
Proof. induction l.
- intros. simpl in H. tauto.
- intros. destruct H; [| (* in case B is in l *) apply IHl; auto; eapply proof_chain_initial; eauto]; subst.
dependent destruction H0.
-- destruct H; admit.
-- admit.
-- pose proof (IHl A B0 H H1) as B0_ind.
pose proof (IHl A (B0 ~> B) H0 H1) as B0_imp_ind.
eapply A2_proof; eauto.
Admitted.

Theorem Deduction: forall (Γ: list formula) (A B: formula),
  A :: Γ |- B -> Γ |- A ~> B.
Proof.
intros Γ A B [l F]. eapply Deduction_lemma; eauto. now left.
Qed.

If you have any questions, or you still have difficulty filling in the remaining proof holes, please feel free to comment!
EDIT: My solution to the proof holes.

Can you explain, how to read the constructor for Inductive proof Γ A : Prop?

How to read the notations "Γ |-- l" - list of formulae l is deducible from the list of formulae Γ? And "Γ |- A"? The formula A (single) is deducible from the list Γ?

The constructor for proof simply says that Γ |- A holds iff there exists some list l such that Γ |-- (A :: l), i.e. iff A is the final element in a sequence of deductions, i.e. A is the conclusion of a derivation.

Please, look at the proof. Thank you!
